# How to enable DateTime if checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm trying to implement that when a user checks the checkbox it enables the certain field like a DateTime in JavaScript.

For instance, by default, the dateTime is disabled, until a user checks the Checkbox, then the DateTime will be enabled.

This is similar to what I've been searching for, which is used to display text when user checks the checkbox:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
    
<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: can you show your HTML ?

Comment: so set the disabled property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by doing something like the following. I've added documentation to the code to offer explanation of how this solution works:

```js
var yourCheckbox = document.querySelector('#myCheck');
var yourDateField = document.querySelector('#yourDateField');

// This function will update the date field's enabled/disabled
// attribute, depending on if the yourCheckbox is checked
function updateYourDateField() {
    
    if(yourCheckbox.checked) {
       yourDateField.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
       yourDateField.disabled = false;
    }
}
   
// Add an event listener to the change event, that causes
// the date field to be enabled/disabled when ever the checkbox
// is clicked and the value changes
yourCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
       
   updateYourDateField();
})
 
// Call this to ensure your date field is in correct state
// when the script is first run
updateYourDateField();
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Disable/Enable control</label>
    <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>The date field</label>
    <input id="yourDateField" type="date" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle also](https://jsfiddle.net/yx2pa8bu/3/)

Comment: Well, this is a quick response with very simple to follow.

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know if the date you entered could be stored in the database. Thanks

Comment: @Cha-LeeChew yes it can be added to the database, however this would require more detail. Perhaps you could ask another question for that?

Comment: I've added my new question regarding this issue. Thanks for the guide tho.

Comment: I'm new to this, can you tell me how to accept this as an answer? :D

Comment: @Cha-LeeChew no problems - you just click the tick next to the answer. It should look like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers